# JavaScript: Append To Multiple Classes

Tags: javascript, html

How can you append content to multiple classes using JavaScript?

This is what I'm working on:

```
<div class="element">
  <p>Existing Content</p>
  <p>Existing Content</p>
</div>

<div class="element">
  <p>Existing Content</p>
  <p>Existing Content</p>
</div>
```

After the function runs, the outcome should be the following:

```
<div class="element">
  <p>Existing Content</p>
  <p>Existing Content</p>
  <p>Added Content</p>
</div>

<div class="element">
  <p>Existing Content</p>
  <p>Existing Content</p>
  <p>Added Content</p>
</div>
```

This is my function so far (not working though):

```
var element = document.querySelectorAll('.element');

for (i = 0; i < element.length; ++i) {
element[i].innerHTML = element.innerHTML + '<p>Added Content</p>';
}
```

**No jQuery Please :)**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're missing the array index `[i]` in your `innerHTML` assignment. Instead of...

```
element[i].innerHTML = element.innerHTML + '<p>Added Content</p>';
```

...you should use:

```
element[i].innerHTML = element[i].innerHTML + '<p>Added Content</p>';
```

Comment: Or the shorter, `element[i].innerHTML += '<p>Added Content</p>';`